# How to check start time and end time in android?

Tags: android, date, time

I develop android app. my problem i get string start time and end time . I want to start time greater than current time  and current time less than end time . How to possible in android my code below. Please help me!!!

```
 String sTartTime ="8:0" ;
    String eNdTime = "20:20";
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatShort = new SimpleDateFormat("H:m", Locale.US);
    String formattedtime = formatShort.format(c.getTime());

 try {

                    String string1 = eNdTime;
                    Date time1 =  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(string1);
                    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar1.setTime(time1);

                    String string2 = sTartTime;
                    Date time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(string2);
                    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar2.setTime(time2);
                    calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                    String someRandomTime = formattedtime;
                    Date d =  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(someRandomTime);
                    Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar3.setTime(d);
                    calendar3.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                    Date x = (Date) calendar3.getTime();
                    if (x.after(calendar1.getTime()) && x.before(calendar2.getTime())) {
                        //checkes whether the current time is between 14:49:00 and 20:11:13.
                         Log.v("log_tag", "Time check today True " );
                    }else{
                        Log.v("log_tag", "Time check today false " );
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

but i can't get date object. i get error Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: i update my code . i can't date object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove import for java.sql.Date . I have tested your code it is working with minor tweaks.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class HelloWorldApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    String sTartTime ="8:0:0" ;
    String eNdTime = "16:20:00";
    String nowTime = "12:20:00";

    try {

        String string1 = eNdTime;
        Date endDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(string1);

        String string2 = sTartTime;
        Date beforeDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(string2);

        String someRandomTime = nowTime;
        Date inBeforeDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(someRandomTime);

        if (inBeforeDate.after(beforeDate) && inBeforeDate.before(endDate)) {
            //checkes whether the current time is between 14:49:00 and 20:11:13.
            System.out.println("log_tag" + "Time check today True " );
        }else{
            System.out.println("log_tag" + "Time check today false " );
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thnax for reply but always print else part and i want to current date start and end time current date. how to possible .please help me

Comment: @crickpatel0024 i have edited the code.Go through it again. .